# curl multi download image

Tags: php, multithreading, curl

I would like if it's possible to optimize this request with multi curl handler ?
Thanks

```
    $array_img = array(
    'https://www.foooooobbbaaarrr.fr/images/1.jpeg',
    'https://www.foooooobbbaaarrr.fr/images/2.jpeg',
    'https://www.foooooobbbaaarrr.fr/images/3.jpeg',
    'https://www.foooooobbbaaarrr.fr/images/4.jpeg');
    foreach ($array_img as $k => $v)
    {
        $ch = curl_init($v);
        $name = ($k + 1).'.jpeg';
        $fp = fopen($name, 'wb');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        fclose($fp);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a very open-ended question, but with the PHP/CURL's multi functions you can at least get all those files in parallel instead of getting them in a serial manner.